# Self- adjoint Linear Transformation and Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, self-adjoint-operators

Let $S$ :$\Bbb C^3 \to \Bbb C^3$ defined by $S(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(2z_2+iz_3,iz_1,z_2)$. Use the definition of self-adjoint to prove S is self-adjoint.

So basically the definition is about $\langle T(x),y\rangle = \langle x,T(y)\rangle,$ but we also know S is self-adjoint if and only if the standard matrix rep of S is Hermitian.
From here, I don't think this S is Hermitian...

Any thoughts or hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree: the transformation that you describe is not self-adjoint relative to the standard inner product.  Perhaps the exercise has a typo.

Comment: The matrix of the transformation (as currently written) is
$$
\pmatrix{0&2&i\\i&0&0\\0&1&0}
$$

Comment: Thanks I will double check with my prof then!